# Problem with Boolean modifier difference

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

So I was trying to use the Boolean modifier in order to cut out windows for a vehicle am working on, when I was satisfied with the shape and applied the modifier, immediately I started getting distortions and the hole changed shape.

[image: Before (cube is hidden)]

[[image: after2]

Comment: please provide blend file.... what you can try: change fast/exact, increase subdiv

Answer (score 1):

the reason is simple, when you added your bool modifier, you added it at the bottom of all modifiers, which means that it is supposed to be last to be applied...

If you apply all your modifiers in the right order from top to bottom, you will get what you wanted, however, if you apply the last one modifier and let the first 2 unapplied it will make something totally different... Just to try it, take your bool modifier and pull it up above the mirror modifier and you will see that result is the same or similar as you got...

If you want to approach it this way, you need to make bools active but not applied and apply all modifiers at the end of your modeling, the other way would be to cut it, disable your modifiers and retopo your model to fit that bool so that rest of your modifiers works as intended...

Sorry for the long essay but simple answer is : **Do not apply random modifiers out of their supposed order**

Comment: Also the boolean workflow and subdivision workflow are not really well suited together because boolean tends to make ugly geometry, when subdivision only really works well with nice clean quad geometry

Comment: Yes that's why I mentioned that you need to repair your topology after bool before using subdivision modifier he has, if your boolean creates face that has 8 vertices, you cannot expect that Blender will make it work somehow, you need to repair it

Comment: Well thanks all, my problem is solved now!